# Cookie not being saved in the browser

Tags: reactjs, spring, authentication, cookies, spring-security

I'm trying to authenticate a React client to a Spring Boot server in **production**. The client sends this request:

```
async function login(credentials) {
    const response = await fetch(url + '/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`,
        },
        credentials: 'include'
    });

    return response;
}
```

In the REST controller I have this endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping("/token")
    public void token(Authentication authentication, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        long expiry = 36000L;

        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuer("now")
                .expiresAt(now.plusSeconds(expiry))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue());
        cookie.setMaxAge(7 * 24 * 60 * 60); // expires in 7 days
        cookie.setSecure(false);

        response.addCookie(cookie);

    }
```

This is the configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://*reactClientIP*:3000")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    }
}
```

The request is successful:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://*reactClientIP*:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 01 May 2023 10:50:43 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJub3ciLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgyOTc0MjQzLCJzY29wZSI6ImFwcCJ9.f9VG5B3H_vd_gUMuKa7IPQ5mI-HC6vxTEFwoZQ1NrRbVuF1e35l5xR8nPMP1qVpMi2DIdEmv8rS0nBs9qmXPH-2b5yXgygyG2u655cA9BvvNc1-U4neAuZFKxpPgg-e4Mj5iNp6nKervakmskEHS6gihp8LLIcI250xcgjPM7QlJ2NhPCl9aXvRiIau7_UcQ1epTAlagWnSnN8UAkXbZ_huSXFSK_k75Mi1POUZ9Kxh0Ab2dUW4gcA66j89UzvMpkNPUFBk7pH_y2EJps0HOzLAP9HPnl0pKUW-NAI8OZQ9YQQn3nlwIDkCI-YjZvQtsexe6yQbizpwP58izMHkrRQ; Max-Age=604800; Expires=Mon, 08 May 2023 10:50:44 GMT
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

However the cookie is not set in the browser.

HttpOnly is set to false, withCredentials to true.

Comment: What broaser do you use? What URL do you call? HTTPS or HTTP? Domain name, IP or localhost?